# Whether to separate tables if part of a table has a relation to another

Tags: sql

I’m learning SQL and have a basic question. I have a transactions table which contains payments and commissions.

A payment:

| ID | Date | Amount | Type | Referrer ID | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| number | date | number | ‘commission’ or ‘payment’ | number | number |

A commission has the same fields as payments, plus two additional fields: qualified and customerPaymentId

| Qualified | Customer Payment ID |
| --- | --- |
| boolean (presumably 0 or 1) | number |

Whenever a payment is made, the balance decreases, and vice versa whenever a commission occurs.

I have a user table too, where a user can have payments but not commissions. Should I separate the transactions table to be 2 tables (commissions and payments), or keep a single transactions table where the user table has a relation with it (rather than a relation to a separate payments table)?

Any advice or pointers would be great too, thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I don’t think I have been very clear at all here. This is the transactions table, that contains both payments and commissions:

| ID | Date | Amount | Type | Referrer ID | Balance | Qualified | Customer Payment Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20/1/22 | 5.00 | COMMISSION | 5454 | 5.00 | 0 | 0001 |
| 2 | 28/1/22 | 4.00 | COMMISSION | 5454 | 9.00 | 0 | 0002 |
| 1 | 20/1/22 | 5.00 | PAYMENT | 5454 | 4.00 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 20/1/22 | 4.00 | PAYMENT | 5454 | 0.00 | NULL | NULL |

The type of ‘commission’ or ‘payment’ is there to determine whether a record is a commission or payment. A commission would have data for the ‘qualified’ and ‘customer payment id’ columns (but payments wouldn’t).

The Customer Payment ID column actually represents a different type of payment - a payment that a user makes for a product. Conversely, the transaction payment is a different payment that pays towards an affiliate’s balance.

The commission.balance and payment.balance represent an overall balance - commissions add to a user’s total balance while payments deduct from it.

To give some better context, this is for an affiliate system - when a customer buys a product, a payment (different - NOT a transaction payment; it’s from another table) is made, with a Customer Payment ID. An affiliate might have earned a commission from that sale, hence a commission record is made (in the transactions table). The amount they are owed is added to the affiliate’s balance. After 3 months, the commission becomes qualified, and the affiliate is paid their commission at the end of that month, hence a payment is made (a payment from the business to the affiliate), which deducts from the affiliate’s balance. It’s not simple to explain, but that is the gist of it if that makes somewhat sense :) I may not have constructed this the best way.

Comment: There's a certain amount of preference here, but personally I'd keep the single table. If anything, I'd have a single table for all transactions, and separate commission_details table that only held the transaction ID and the extra fields.

Comment: Is CustomerPaymentID a foreign key to Payments? What do commission.balance and payment.balance represent? Are they different, or a copy? Why does the payment table have a type of payment or commission?

Comment: We need more information about what you're trying to model.

Comment: Interesting ideas and comments, thank you both. @Joel - if I did it with the commission_details table but wanted to display the data together, would it mean I’d have to perform joins, which would be expensive?

Comment: @Schwern - Fair comments. I have updated my question as I don’t think I’ve been clear enough.

Comment: @user8758206 It's a little difficult to follow what's happening, but it seems you have a bunch of things which have *some* overlap in their fields but aren't actually the same?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. The payments and commissions for example are similar, both affecting the balance, but a user can have payments but not commissions

Comment: Yes, you would need a join, but I wouldn't expect it to be slow if you have defined the tables and indexes properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little difficult to follow what's happening, but it seems you have a bunch of things which have some overlap in their fields but aren't actually the same. But sometimes you want to look at them all together.

I would suggest making separate tables for each kind of thing, and then a [create a view](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_view.asp) to bring them all together.

For example...

```
create view transactions as
  select created_on, amount, 'COMMISSION' as type, balance
  from commissions
union all
  select created_on, amount, 'PAYMENT' as type, balance
  from payments
```

We use `union` instead of `union all` for performance. `union` removes duplicate rows which means the database has to do more work and operations are slower and more complicated. There are no duplicates in this instance.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/wpYz9eUb)

Comment: I didn’t know you could do that. Would creating a view like this impact performance? The payments and commissions will be frequently queried together, which is why I initially put them together (in a Mongo DB - im changing to Postgres)

Comment: @user8758206 Some queries may be faster because Postgres can use parallel workers to query both tables. Just [be sure you're configured for parallel queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/how-parallel-query-works.html). Other operations, like `order by` will be slower; rather than a single index scan, it must merge two index scans. Note that using `union all` is faster than using `union`.